# Can I backup Jenkins with settings, Jobs and Plugins?

Tags: jenkins

is there any way to make a bakup of jenkins, all installed plugins and settings?
Or is there any way to install plugins via console?

Regards
*n00n*

Answer (score 0):

You can backup your Jenkins jobs and configurations using the **[thinBackup](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/thinBackup)** Plugin.